# Using refs to manage callbacks between React and JS objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-ref

Let's say I have the following code:

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState('status_a')
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = new WebSocket('ws://foo.com')
    socket.onclose = () => console.log(`socket closed while status was ${status}`)
    setSocket(socket)
  }, [])

  // ... some code that changes status in response to user input
}
```

So there's a bug here, because when socket.onclose fires, status will always be the initial value, "status_a".

One solution, using refs:

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState('status_a')
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState()
  const callbacks = useRef({})

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = new WebSocket('ws://foo.com')
    socket.onclose = () => callbacks.current.socketOnClose()
    setSocket(socket)
  }, [])

  // ... some code that changes status in response to user input

  // this gets redefined on every render, so it always has the new value of status
  callbacks.current.socketOnClose = () => {
    console.log(`socket closed while status was ${status}`)
  }
}
```

It works, but smells a bit weird to me. Any better ideas?

This example only has one state dependency in the callback, but the real code has many dependencies, so setting up a change handler for each one that redefines the callback would also be clunky.

Answer (score 3):

I think using a `ref` is the right solution, but I just don't think you should use it for the callback, but for the values you want the callback to have access to:

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState('status_a')
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState()

  const statusRef = useRef(status)

  useEffect(() => {
    statusRef.current = status
  }, [status])

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = new WebSocket('ws://foo.com')

    socket.onclose = () => console.log(`socket closed while status was ${statusRef .current}`)

    setSocket(socket)
  }, [])

  // ... some code that changes status in response to user input
}
```

Why? Let's see what the [React documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef#referencing-a-value-with-a-ref) says:

> **Referencing Values with Refs:**
>
> When you want a component to “remember” some information, but you don’t want that information to trigger new renders, you can use a `ref`.

This is similar to your case where your `onclose` callback, and therefore the `useEffect` that contains it, both have a dependency on some data (`status`), but you do not want a change on that data to re-run your `useEffect` and socket setup logic.

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice alternative. Could get a bit verbose if there are many state variables that need to be used in the callback, but then we could use the same trick of having a single container object as the ref, and assigning all the necessary variables as properties of that object in a single useEffect when any of them change.